# Помощь в обработке команд

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

**По пользовательской команде** `!отправь <текст>` **бот должен:**

- Выполнить команду (отправить соответствующий текст).
- Удалить сообщение пользователя, от которого пришла команда.

Библиотека *discord.py* — последняя версия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть небольшая неточность, потому что в команде нельзя удалить точное сообщение(либо я не знаю как), поэтому я просто удаляю последнее сообщение с помощью функции `purge()`

```
@bot.command(aliases=['отправь'])
async def send(ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(text)
```